# MongoDB find query with $ref and $id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling with a mongodb query.

Given this query 1:

```
db.procedures.find({'procedure.name':'nameOfMyProcedure'})
```

and this query 2:

```
db.procedure_executions.find({'foo.bar':'whatever'})
```

Query 1 returns a lot of procedure objects that look like this in shortened version:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5564df8d30041530fb68e1eb"),
    "_class": "eu.whatever.model.db.impl.DbProcedureExecutionImpl",
    "procedure": {
        "_class": "eu.whatever.common.model.impl.ProcedureImpl",
        "className": "eu.whatever",
        "name": "nameOfMyProcedure",
        "kind": "METHOD",
        "arguments": []
    },
    "caller": {
        "$ref": "procedure_executions",
        "$id": ObjectId("5564df8d30041530fb68e1e8")
    }
}
```

The resulting objects of query 2 are referenced as "caller" in query 1.

**How can I filter procedures (query 1) by the referenced caller and its attributes (query 2) in a single nested query?**

I came across $in. Is it possible to add a query to another collection (procedure_executions) within $in?

Answer (score 0):

"I'm new here myself", but try:

```
db.procedures.find(
     {'procedure.name':'nameOfMyProcedure'},
     {'caller.$ref': 'procedure_executions'})
```

From [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and):

> #### NOTE:
>
> MongoDB provides an implicit `AND` operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit `AND` with the `$and` operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

Comment: my question might was ambiguous, the name of the referenced collection 'procedure_executions' is fixed, but the procedure_execution objects need to fulfil certain criteria (like the name attribute of the object). Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not because this specifies just the name of the referenced collection. The question should be more precise now. Any idea how to solve it?